# How to make text bold in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display my text as bold inside php echo code and also wanted to increase font size, but its not working. can any pone guide me what wrong in my code how to make it work ??????
below is my code

```
<table style="line-height: 1.5;">

  <tr><td><?php echo <b> $result[0]["type1"];  </b>?></td></tr>   
   
    <tr><table>
```

i tried both strong as well as  tag, but failed to achieve desired result

Comment: Just to note that the b tag now has semantics attached and although I think most browsers will still render the text in bold, if all you want is bold then use CSS not an HTML tag. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Answer (score 3):

> How to make text bold in PHP?

You don't.  The front-end styling is handled by CSS/HTML.

This is a syntax error in PHP:

```
echo <b> $result[0]["type1"];  </b>
```

Just as with the rest of your HTML, the HTML code goes *outside* of the `<?php ?>` tags:

```
<td><b><?php echo $result[0]["type1"]; ?></b></td>
```

Alternatively, you *could* include the HTML in the PHP if you *really* want to, it would just be a string value like any other string:

```
<td><?php echo "<b>" . $result[0]["type1"] . "</b>"; ?></td>
```

Alternatively, you could skip the `<b>` entirely and just use CSS:

```
<td style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $result[0]["type1"]; ?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, its working, can I also increase font size ????

Comment: @Chand: Yes, you can apply any styling you like to your HTML.  This is probably a good time for you to start learning about CSS.

Comment: yes i will as i am student, but may i knew in current code how can i increase font size

Comment: @Chand: You can add [a `font-size` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) to the `style` attribute on that `<td>` element.  For example: `style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.5rem;"`